# angular js treeview getting slower and slower

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs, angularjs-directive, treeview

I am trying to make a treeview control in angular js.

I have used the angular js directive( referred this link : [angularjs treeview](http://jsfiddle.net/eu81273/8LWUc/18/))

I have modified the above for having a big tree that contain tags.

My fiddle : [fiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/8SNgp/2/)

```
   //angular module
  var myApp = angular.module('myApp', ['angularTreeview']);

  //test controller
  myApp.controller('myController', function($scope){

      $scope.clean_tree = function()
      {
          $scope.roleList = [];
      };

       $scope.show_tree = function () {
        //debugger;
        console.log("tag start : " + new Date());
          //$scope.tagList = eval(abc);
        $scope.roleList = $scope.roleList_tag;
        $scope.$apply();
        console.log("tag end : " + new Date());
    };
```

**The problem**

The rendering of the tree gets slower and slower if I continuously follow this pattern:

1. click on : Tree Structure
2. click on : clean
3. Go To 1.

I dont understand why this is becoming slower and slower when i follow this pattern

Comment: sorry for the incorrect fiddle link : updated the link now

Comment: It could be a bug in the implementation of the treeview, that they attach to DOM elements but forgets to detach them when the model changes? You may be able to use: https://github.com/dotJEM/angular-tree to have more control over what is going on.

Comment: thanks for that , will try. Just curious about" that they attach to DOM elements but forgets to detach them when the model changes". I really want to understand what you mean by that. I am curious because we are developing an angular application and **we never do anything like detach dom** and i dont know why our webpage is eating more and more RAM over time. Also it becomes painful to operate the page after its opened for a long time. Could you please give me some link/post so that could know this detaching mechanism because we never do anythn when model changes eg. **ng-repeat does it all**

Comment: That is classical memory leaking, basically you may remove a DOM element, but if you have references to that element in your JavaScript, then as long as the object holding that reference is alive, the DOM tree you "removed" will remain as a detached DOM tree. When angular does it's stuff it removes and adds DOM elements all the time, and many custom directives etc. does the same. If they forget to do proper "dispose" where required, you have a memory leak.

Comment: i understand that the only problem we have over here is that we are dealing with SPA and we have memory leaks. Could you help me with some reference material in this regard so that I could deal with these memory leaks(specifically concerning angular js)